# Is my fstream bad or not good()?

Tags: c++, iostream, fstream

So I have a .cpp file with a Function which recieves a filename, and should return a String with the contents of the file (actualy modified contents, I modified the code to make it more understandable, but that doesn't have any effect on my problem). The problem is that `f.good()` is returning `false` and the loop, which reads the file is not working.
CODE :

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Form21.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>



    string ReadAndWrite(char* a){
    char filename[8];
    strcpy_s(filename,a);
    string output;
    char c;
    ifstream f(filename,ios::in);
    output+= "Example text"; // <-- this writes and returns just fine!
    c = f.get();

    while (f.good())
      { 

    output+= c;
    c= f.get();         
          }

    return output;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on why this is happening?
Does it have something to do with, that this is a seperate .cpp file( it doesnt even throw out an error when I remove `#include <fstream>`).
Maybe there is a different kind of method to make the loop?
I'll be very happy to hear any suggestions on how to fix this *or* maybe a different method on how to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there's really no reason to copy the file name you receive -- you can just use it as-is. Second, almost any loop of the form `while (stream.good())`, `while (!stream.bad())`, `while (stream)`, etc., is *nearly* certain to be buggy. What you normally want to do is check whether reading some data worked.

Alternatively, you can skip using a loop at all. There are a couple of ways to do this. One that works nicely for shorter files looks like this:

```
string readfile(std::string const &filename) { 
    std::ifstream f(filename.c_str());   
    std::string retval;

    retval << f.rdbuf();
    return retval;
}
```

That works nicely up to a few tens of kilobytes (or so) of data, but starts to slow down on larger files. In such a case, you usually want to use `ifstream::read` to get the data, something along this general line:

```
std::string readfile(std::string const &filename) {
    std::ifstream f(filename.c_str());

    f.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
    size_t size = f.tellg();

    std::string retval(size, ' ');
    f.seekg(0);
    f.read(&retval[0], size);
    return retval;
}
```

Edit: If you need to process the individual characters (not just read them) you have a couple of choices. One is to separate it into phases, where you read all the data in one phase, and do the processing in a separate phase. Another possibility (if you just need to look at individual characters during processing) is to use something like `std::transform` to read data, do the processing, and put the output into a string:

```
struct character_processor { 
    char operator()(char input) { 
        // do some sort of processing on each character:
        return ~input;
    }
};

std::transform(std::istream_iterator<char>(f),
               std::istream_iterator<char>(),
               std::back_inserter(result),
               character_processor());
```

Comment: See, the thing is that in the loop i actualy will need to analize each char, and change some chars to different ones, also i will add lines.
Maby my mind is stuck to my method, but i am not sure if i am going to achieve what i want with your suggested method.

Answer (score 0):

I would check that strlen(a) is not greater than 7...
You might overrun `filename` and get a file name that doesn't exist.

Not relating the problem, I would re-write the function:

```
string ReadAndWrite(string a) {  // string here, if you are into C++ already
    string filename;  // also here
    filename = a;  // simpler
    string output;
    char c;
    ifstream f(filename.c_str());  // no need for ios::in (but needs a char *, not a string
    output+= "Example text"; // <-- this writes and returns just fine!
    f >> c;  // instead c = f.get();

    while (f) // no need for f.good())
      { 

        output+= c;
        f >> c; // again, instead c= f.get();         
      }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: even if i change the 'filename' with a static "001.txt" which is the needed file name, it still doesnt work :/

Comment: operator>> is not the same as get(). By default operator>> will drop all proceeding white space before performing the read into the variable.

Comment: This `while(f)` is just as bad as `while(f.good())`. In normal situations you would use neither.

Answer (score -3):

Might I suggest using fopen? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/ It takes in a filename and returns a file pointer.  With that you can use fgets to read the file line by line http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/

Comment: Please don't!!! :-)  C++ streams are much more convenient and safer, auto-closing etc... That's the way to do it, but needed to know how to use them

Comment: It's ok in C. But streams are superior. If you use fopen in C++ it means you don't expliot the language, and writing more vulnerable code. Like using goto or asm variable assignments in C.